# Mix option pattern with connection strings

Tags: .net-core, configuration

I would like to create a settings class for Event Hubs as follows:

```cs
public class EventHubsOptions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerGroup { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Which I would then configure with the following:

```cs
services.Configure< EventHubsOptions >( Configuration.GetSection( "EventHubs" ) );
```

But that means I need to write my appsettings file as follows:

```json
  "EventHubs": {
    "Name": "EventHubName",
    "ConsumerGroup": "consumergroup",
    "ConnectionString": "xxx"
  }
```

Is there a way that would allow me to put the connection string within the ConnectionsStrings section of the appsettings? Something like this:

```json
{
  "EventHubs": {
    "Name": "EventHubName",
    "ConsumerGroup": "consumergroup"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "xxx",
    "EventHubsConnection" : "xxx",
    "StorageConnection": "xxx"
  }
}
```

How would I configure the EventHubsOptions class during startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way -

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.Configure<EventHubsOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("EventHubs"));

        // These are run after all Configure<TOptions>
        services.PostConfigure<EventHubsOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("EventHubsConnection");
        });
    }
```

The [PostConfigure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ipostconfigureoptions-1.postconfigure?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) can be used to override the configuration. More about it is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#options-post-configuration).

Basically, we are overriding `ConnectionString` value after all configuring of `TOptions` is finished.